# Cancel a previous Jquery Form Submit on Key Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, forms, submit

I have a search form that I am trying to do dynamic type down on. On keyup I am submitting the form. However I am running into issues with large data sets. The issue is that each form submit always returns a result and that result is always inserted into the DOM. For example when I type in the 4th character on keyup it submits the form and returns 100 matching results. When typing in the 5th character it returns only 2 results. The execution time of the 5th character returns faster then the 4th. So what ends up happening is it paints the 2 results in the DOM and then the 4th returns and paints the 100 results into the DOM.

Is there a way to cancel or ignore the previous form post results if a keyup event happens after the submit?  Here is the Form and the submit via javascript

```html
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "get",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "Breweries"
}))
{
    <input id="brewerySearchInput" class="form-control page-header-input" placeholder="Search" type="search" name="searchTerm" />
}

<script>
    $("#brewerySearchInput").keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length >= 3 || $(this).val().length == 0) {
            $('#form0').delay(200).submit();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think yours is a classic case of using `debounce` function.

> Debouncing enforces that a function not be called again until a certain amount of time has passed without it being called. As in "execute this function only if 100 milliseconds have passed without it being called.

You will be making too many unnecessary backend requests otherwise. Check it out https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: BINGO!!!  That worked like a charm!  For people following here is the adjusted code based on the answer above to reference

Answer (score 0):

@bhabisha Kumar nailed this on the head.  The debounce function is exactly what I needed to get the code to work.  Here is the final working code.

```
<script>

    function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
        var timeout;
        return function () {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function () {
                timeout = null;
                if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
            if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
        };
    };

    var myEfficientFn = debounce(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length >= 3 || $(this).val().length == 0) {
            $('#form0').submit();
        }

    }, 300);

    $("#brewerySearchInput").keyup(myEfficientFn);
</script>
```